# Get error org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException when running the selenium code

Tags: selenium-webdriver

getting the below error

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException

Firefox : 32.0

Eclipse : Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)

Comment: Which jar and firefox u used

Comment: Provide ur code

Comment: Either use jar 2.53 with firefox 45.0 or upgrade jar 3.5 with firefox 55.0 and download gecko driver and use it, in your case you have to downlad selenium jar below 2.51

Comment: I got same error when i run a script on firefox 47 with selenium jar 2.53 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your firefox You need to install geckodriver  from this link:

[Gecko driver download from here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

and then set the setProperty()

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\software and tools\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

If you are using selenium jar 2.53 and browser firefox 45.0, then no need to set gecko driver:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```